# Java code works on eclipse but not on command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a java program and it is properly running on Eclipse, there are no errors and the program gives accurate output. However when I compile it using command prompt it gives me 39 errors.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static void main (String args [])

    {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame (); // making a frame in which we will add all the
                                    // components
    FrameWork work = new FrameWork ();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setBounds (10,10,700,500);
    frame.setResizable(false); // making the frame non resizeable so that components are not misplaced
    frame.add (work);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible (true);


    } // main ends here

} // main class ends here 



class FrameWork extends JPanel 
{
 // panel in which all the components are added 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();

    JTextArea jarea = new JTextArea();
    JTextField jfield = new JTextField();
    // Buttons that can be used to switch between standard IO NIO and NIO2
    JButton IO   = new JButton ("Standard IO");
    JButton NIO  = new JButton ("New IO");
    JButton NIO2 = new JButton ("New IO2");
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

FrameWork ()

{



// setting the lay out null so that componenets can be places at respective postions 
add(panel);
setLayout (null);
setBounds (0,0,700,500);
setBackground(Color.white);

add(jarea);
jarea.setBounds(5,85,670,360);
//setting border arround the JText area 
jarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
jarea.add(scroll);


add(jfield);
jfield.setBounds(10,10,650,25);


 // adding Standard IO button and Implemnting action listener
add(IO);
IO.setBounds (50,40,150,40);
IO.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae) 

    {       
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("test.txt");
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(reader);
            jarea.read(buff,null);
            buff.close();

        } 

        catch (IOException e) {


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ae) {


    }});



// adding Standard NIO button and Implementing action listener


add(NIO);
NIO.setBounds (250,40,150,40);
NIO.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae) {
// some part of this code from java docs

        Path file = Paths.get("test.txt");
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) 

        {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                jarea.read(reader,null);
            }

        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ae) {


    }});

// adding Standard NIO2 button and Implemnting action listener


add(NIO2);
NIO2.setBounds (450,40,150,40);
NIO2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae) {
        try
        {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024*1024);             
        Path file = Paths.get("test.txt");                          
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Files.newByteChannel(file);               
        int counter =0;
        int flag = 0;
        int enter = 0;
        while(counter != -1)
        {
                buffer.rewind ();                                               
                counter = rbc.read(buffer);                                         
                buffer.rewind();
                flag++;
                for(enter =0 ; enter <= counter-1 ; enter++)
                {
                    byte by = buffer.get();                                 
                    jarea.append(""+(char)by);                              
                }
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e){}


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ae) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ae) {

    }});


}   // constructor ends 



}   //FrameWork Class ends
```

**Errors:**

[image]

Comment: What errors is it giving you precisely?

Comment: This is most likely because you do not have the corect jars in the classpath. Can you provide a couple of the errors?

Comment: @Nivas: and what JARs would those be?  The `import`s only refer to standard Java SE classes.

Comment: Could you show us the command you used to start the application from command line? And show us the error message(s).

Comment: I have added the pictures of errors which I am getting while compiling the program. I am using javac command for compiling the code

Comment: Maybe `java -version` gives java 6 (1.6) on the command line, as try-with-resources is new in java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: based on the images of errors that you uploaded later, it looks like you are using a Java 1.6 or earlier compiler.  Do java -version to see what version  you are using.

Update your windows path to use the java 1.7 version that you have elsewhere on your machine.

Comment: based on your image, it looks like your java compiler is older than java 1.7 and you are using try with resources which was introduced in 1.7

Answer (score 0):

In Command Line - Remove the imported packages on top , when it is a single file and standalone application.

Check List:-

Make user the `libraries` are available to the existing location.

`Set the class path` perfectly.

Execute the below commands to ensure they environmental variables are set properly for jdk and jre

```
c:\javac 
c:\java
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today.  My program was working fine in the Eclipse debugger but misbehaving from the OS command line.  It finally turned out to be a CLASSPATH issue.  My code was incompatible with a JAR that I had included in my CLASSPATH environment variable for the OS shell.  This JAR was not even required for my program.  For Eclipse I had only linked the requisite JARs, so this problem did not manifest in the Eclipse debugger.  After excluding the offending JAR from my CLASSPATH, the problem disappeared.